# Is $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac1{2^{k^2}}$ rational? Transcendental?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, transcendental-numbers

Is $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac1{2^{k^2}}$ rational?

Clearly this series is convergent (compare to geometric series with ratio 1/2). I'm sure it's irrational since a rational number written in base 2 will have either a terminating or repeating decimal representation. But the hard part is to show this representation in question doesn't repeat. (cf 
https://www.google.com/search?q=periodic+rational+base&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a )

Can you show this number is transcendental?

Comment: It is *not* hard to show that the binary representation does not repeat: There are arbitrarily long sequences of zeroes.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_theta_function

Comment: @WillJagy: does that say anything about the transcendentality of the limit?

Comment: @robjohn, I'm checking. But my guess is that this is unknown.

Comment: @robjohn, in chapter 10 of Complex Analysis by Stein and Shakarchi, they refer to two special cases of Jacobi's theta functions, of interest here, from page 298, $$ \theta(\tau) = \sum_{n = - \infty}^\infty q^{n^2},  $$ with the understanding that $q = e^{\pi i \tau}$ with $\tau$ in the upper half plane.

Comment: My gut feeling is that demonstrating this is going to be pretty tricky: if $e^{\pi i \tau} = \frac{1}{2}$, then $\tau = -\log(2)/(\pi i)$, which is in the upper half plane, but is also the kind of argument which we have no good data about the algebraicity/transcendentality of $j(\tau)$. If one could show that $j(-\log(2)/(\pi i))$ was algebraic or transcendental simply, this question would be a gimme. This paper may also be worth a look: http://goo.gl/2iI4YT Corollary 2.3 specifically.

Comment: Pardon what may be a dumb idea, but isn't this sort of number perfect for a Diophantine approximation argument - it's too easily approximated by rationals, hence must be transcendental?

Answer (score 1):

The question was asked, and a reference to a proof of transcendentality was given, at the accepted answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/55397/is-this-number-already-known-to-be-transcendental-is-there-a-survey-about-up-to) at MO.

Actually, it seems it has also been answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/459124/for-integer-k-1-is-sum-i-0-infty-1-k2i-transcendental-or-algebr?) at m.se.

Comment: Wadim gives an earlier reference, his adviser, Nesterenko, Y. (1996). "Modular Functions and Transcendence Problems". Comptes Rendus de l'Académie des Sciences. Série I. Mathématique 322 (10): 909–914.

Comment: I don't seem to be able to order a pdf of this.

Comment: You can buy a copy at http://cat.inist.fr/?aModele=afficheN&cpsidt=3105796

Comment: Gerry, it is less convenient, but at some point i can drive to msri and use their access to online versions of journals at ucb. This would include both the short version, six pages, and a much longer thing in Mat Sbornik http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=sm&paperid=158&option_lang=eng

Comment: Requested a translation of the 30 page item, the translation series is called Sbornik Mathematics. Probably work. I'm guessing the six page version is prettied up where he did the highlights in a more readable manner and did the English himself.